# Renaming news section leads to 404

Tags: sections, 404

I'm pretty new to Craft, just installed my first one. I've checked the docs, but I couldn't find any useful hints anymore and I think it should work.

I'm trying to rename the default news section to post. I changed everything admin side from news to page, but the path `http://site.local/post/2016/we-just-installed-craft` leads to a 404 page. The `http://site.local/post` page lists the entries correctly.

I also renamed the `news` folder in the templates to `post`. If I change it back to news, the 404 problem is resolved, but obviously I want to understand why it still wants to access that folder.

Sections page looks like this
[image]

I don't have any custom route set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

Admin was a bit confusing on the UX side, I didn't realize that `edit entry types` and clicking the `name` of the section leads to different pages.